# Laravel user roles with middleware not working

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel project where I'm using middleware to create users roles like admin/moderator, and I want to restrict access to routes only. I have users table with a role column where my user role is 'admin'. When I go to /posts page in web.php I should be able to access it since I'm admin, but for some reason I get 404 not found. Can someone please help me?

**web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('types', function () {
    Route::get('/posts',[\App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class,'posts']);
})->middleware('roles:admin');
```

**app/Http/Controllers/ProductController.php**

```
 public function posts(){
    $product = Product::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(21);
    return view('posts', ['products' => $product]);
 }
```

**app/Http/Middleware/UserRoles.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserRoles
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
    {
      return collect($roles)->contains(auth()->user()->roles) ? $next($request) : back();
    }
}
```

**Kernel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;
use App\Http\Middleware\UserRoles;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
  protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'roles' => UserRoles::class,
];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You has a problem in web.php - get in get is not allowed. Use Route::group or Route::middleware

```
Route::middleware('roles:admin', function () {
     Route::get('/posts',[\App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class,'posts']);
});
```